# State in useEffect is not updating

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

I have this component that when I click on the button it toggles the state of isMenuActive, the problem comes when implementing the function inside the useEffect, for a strange reason when I try to access to the value of isMenuActive inside the closeTooltip function it always reflects **false**, even though the value of isMenuActive has changed to **true**.

```
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import Tooltip from "./Tooltip";

export default function Navbar() {
  const [isMenuActive, setIsMenuActive] = useState(false);
  const menu = useRef(null);

  const handleOnClick = (e) => {
    setIsMenuActive((prev) => !prev);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const closeTooltip = (e) => {
      if (menu.current && !menu.current.contains(e.target)) {
        //Here isMenuActive is always false, even after using handleOnClick func
        console.log(isMenuActive);
      }
    };
    document.addEventListener("click", closeTooltip, true);
    return () => document.removeEventListener("click", closeTooltip, true);
  }, [menu]);

  return (
    <button
      className="navbar__notifications"
      aria-label="Notificaciones"
      name="notification"
      onClick={handleOnClick}
      ref={menu}
    >
      {isMenuActive && <Tooltip title="Notificaciones" />}
    </button>
  );
}
```

Any idea of why is this happening?

Comment: Why are you using `addEventListener` inside  a react hook? Adding event listener's like this is not a good practice at all.

Comment: Check this one https://codesandbox.io/s/function-component-with-usestate-forked-6prqt8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`menu` (with `useRef`) always refers to the same object, so `useEffect` won't be triggered for every change of `menu` (even though `menu.current`).

[`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) is only triggered in 3 cases

- Props change with dependencies
- States change with dependencies
- Initial mounted component

The log you get from `closeTooltip` is from the initial `useEffect` call (initial mounted component)

For the fix, you should add `isMenuActive` (state changes) in the dependency list of `useEffect` instead. That will keep listening to `isMenuActive` state changes and update your `closeTooltip` event accordingly.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const closeTooltip = (e) => {
      if (menu.current && !menu.current.contains(e.target)) {
        //Here isMenuActive is always false, even after using handleOnClick func
        console.log(isMenuActive);
      }
    };
    document.addEventListener("click", closeTooltip, true);
    return () => document.removeEventListener("click", closeTooltip, true);
  }, [isMenuActive]);
```

You can check [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-zzjdb7) for the test